# Unable to start my application in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am developing my first ios app with sending mail. I wrote the code and tap on "Run". I am not able to run my application . I got below error can any one give me some suggestions to solve my issue.

2013-12-23 19:07:59.314 gps[3818:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mail.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d01012 0x11e3e7e 0x1d89fb1 0xc8fe41 0xc115f8 0xc110e7 0xc3bb58 0x345019 0x11f7663 0x1cfc45a 0x343b1c 0x2087e7 0x208dc8 0x208ff8 0x209232 0x1583d5 0x15876f 0x158905 0x161917 0x233b 0x125157 0x125747 0x12694b 0x137cb5 0x138beb 0x12a698 0x1f3adf9 0x1f3aad0 0x1c76bf5 0x1c76962 0x1ca7bb6 0x1ca6f44 0x1ca6e1b 0x12617a 0x127ffc 0x1f7d 0x1ea5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: post your code what are you doing

Comment: see in your storyboard or in xib file outlets is properly joined or not.

Comment: This is usually a symptom that the storyboard or XIB contains a reference to a method or property in a class that is not found in that class, either because you've connected to the wrong class or because you omitted the method/property.

Comment: Please detail to me what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this error might be this bellow possible issue.

- If you are using storyboards then you are forget to setting identifier of view-controller.
- Facing This error normally  because of you are forget connect `IBOutlate` to controls in `xib` or storyboard
- Check in to your project `firstViewcontroller` storyboard or xib.
- If you are setting two `IBOutlate` with same control then you also got the same error in `XIB` or in story Bord overwrite last `IBOutlet` but its `IBAction` is not.
  check Properly your `xib` and its control that connect well or correct  or not.

Answer (score 2):

it's a simple error.
go to your storybord, and right-click the yellow circle with the white square on your view controller.
you will see that one of the outlets has a warning near it. click the X, and re-connect the outlet.

this type of error happens when you miss-connect an outlet.